# Block certain URL on unix (MAC OS X)?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it technically possible to block certain websites from being accessed on Mac OS via separate from browser program? Kind of hosts file in Windows? I need to make a project and I would like to do that. 
I imagine it can be done if I make some sort of proxy and set my browser to it, but is there any more user friendly way? Like editing some file to redirect certain URLs to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hosts` file exists on the Mac as well, and can be used to block access to certain URLs in the same way as in other systems. You can find it in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Well, technically, not a certain URL, but a certain host. As you can't block certain URL w/o blocking its host with this approach.